# Expected time of reaching 0 of a simple symmetric random walk

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Consider the symmetric, simple random walk on $S = \{0, 1, \ldots , k\}$ for $k \in \mathbb N$.

Let $$T = \min \{ n \in \mathbb N_0|X_n = 0\}$$

be the first time where the process reaches $0$ and let
$a_x = E\{T|X0 = x\}$ be the expected time for reaching $0$ when starting at $x \in S$.

ax satisfies $a_0 = 0$ and $$a_x =\frac12 a_{x−1} + \frac12 a_{x+1} + 1 \tag{1}$$ 
for all $x ∈ \{1, 2, . . . , k − 1\}$.

How do I find a relation similar to $(1)$ for $a_k$?

I am not sure what happens at the barrier of a simple symmetric random walk, does it go to k-1 next with probability $1$ or can it stay where it is too?

Solve the resulting system of equations to obtain the values $a_0, a_1, . . . , a_k$. I cannot do this (possibly because I do not know ak)

Comment: If you know where ax =0.5ax−1 + 0.5ax+1 + 1 for all x ∈ {1, 2, . . . , k − 1} comes from, you should know how to adapt this to x = k. Do you?

Comment: Im unsure as to what happens at the barrier though, if it is in state k, does it step down with probability 1, or step down with probability 1/2 and stay put with probability 1/2?

Comment: Both are possible -- it depends on the precise statement of the exercise.